# Find the planes that is perpendicular to a vector and tangent set

Tags: vectors

Find the planes that is perpendicular to the vector $(0,0,1)'$ and tangent to the set:

$${x\in \mathbb{R} ^3:x^2+2xz+2y^2+2yz+3z^2=1}$$

The answer is $x\in \mathbb{R} ^3: z =\pm \frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}$

My confusions:
The planes that is perpendicular to the vector should be $z=1$.

However, I am confused with the concept "perpendicular to the vector $(0,0,1)'$". Imagine I have a plane $z=1$ and I reduce this plane slowly from $z=1$ to $z=0$, is every plane in this range perpendicular to the vector $(0,0,1)'$? Can I say $z=-1$ also perpendicular to this vector?

Base on the plane which is perpendicular to the vector, how do we make the plane also satisfy the required tangent set.

[image]

Comment: The question is most likely talking about the bundle of planes that have surface normals (0,0,1). Given the standard equation $ax+by+cz+d=0$ for planes with surface normal $(a,b,c)$ and closest distance $d$ of the plane to the origin, this means all planes with the form $z=-d$ with free variable $d$ are scanned. The task is to find $d$ such that the plane is tangent to the surface with the mixed quadratic equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once it is obvious that the required set of planes are the horizontal planes, the tangential plane enforces a local minimum of the ellipsoid surface both with respect to variations in $x$ as in variations with respect to $y$. This is implemented by setting the two partial derivaties of $x^2+2xz+2y^2+2yz+3z^2=1$ to zero, so
$2x+2z=0$ and
$4y+2z=0$.
Then substituting $x=-z$ in $x^2+2xz+2y^2+2yz+3z^2=1$ becomes $2z^2+2y^2+2yz=1$
and furthermore substituting $y=-z/2$ gives $3z^2/2=1$, so $z^2=2/3$ and $z=\pm \sqrt{2/3}$.